# Are optional dependencies with Dist::Zilla possible?

Tags: perl, dependencies, dist-zilla

I want to make some of my dependencies detected by [Dist::Zilla](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist%3a%3aZilla) optional. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Dist::Zilla::Plugin::Prereqs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Dist-Zilla/lib/Dist/Zilla/Plugin/Prereqs.pm) documentation says you can define them as:

```
[Prereqs / RuntimeRecommends]
Some::Optional::Module = 0
```

Though though [apparently](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.module-authors/2011/07/msg9293.html) it's not supported by the common clients (or at least wasn't last summer).